# Передать текст из одного TextField в другой.

Tags: java, jtextfield

Есть две JFrame. На одной расположен TextField1, на другой - TextField2 и Button1. Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы после нажатия на кнопку текст из TextField2 отправился в TextField1?

Comment: взять его из первого и положить во второй? а ты как делал? где код?

Comment: Вот именно, что я не представляю, как это можно сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frame1.java

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Frame1 extends JFrame{
    private JTextField textField1 = new JTextField(20);
    public Frame1() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(textField1);
    }
    public JTextField getTextField() {
        return textField1;
    }
}
```

Frame2.java

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

    public class Frame2 extends JFrame {
        private JTextField textField2 = new JTextField(20);
        private JButton button = new JButton("OK");

        public Frame2(final JTextField textField) {
            setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    textField.setText(textField2.getText());
                    textField2.setText(null);
                }
            });
            add(textField2);
            add(button);
        }
    }
```

Main.java

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Frame1 frame1 = new Frame1();
        frame1.pack();
        frame1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame1.setVisible(true);

        Frame2 frame2 = new Frame2(frame1.getTextField());
        frame2.pack();
        frame2.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame2.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Пример 2х окошек на основе одного класса:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout ;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent ;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction ;
import javax.swing.Action ;
import javax.swing.JButton ;
import javax.swing.JDialog ;
import javax.swing.JTextField ;

//model interface
interface IHaveText
{
    public void setText ( String text ) ;

    public String getText () ;
}

// view & controller + model implementation
public class CustomFrame extends JDialog implements IHaveText
{
    private JTextField textField = new JTextField () ;

    // main window
    public CustomFrame ()
    {
        super () ;

        // do common init
        init ( "Parent window" ) ;

        // do custom init
        // create actions
        Action showChild = new AbstractAction ( "Show child" )
        {

            @ Override
            public void actionPerformed ( ActionEvent e )
            {
                new CustomFrame ( CustomFrame.this ).setVisible ( true ) ;
            }
        } ;

        // add buttons
        add ( new JButton ( showChild ) ) ;
    }

    // child window
    public CustomFrame ( final CustomFrame parent )
    {
        super ( parent, true ) ;

        // do common init
        init ( "Child window" ) ;

        // do custom init
        // create actions
        Action fromParent = new AbstractAction ( "Copy from parent" )
        {
            @ Override
            public void actionPerformed ( ActionEvent e )
            {
                setValueFrom ( CustomFrame.this, parent ) ;
            }
        } ;

        Action toParent = new AbstractAction ( "Copy to parent" )
        {
            @ Override
            public void actionPerformed ( ActionEvent e )
            {
                setValueFrom ( parent, CustomFrame.this ) ;
            }
        } ;

        // add buttons
        add ( new JButton ( fromParent ) ) ;
        add ( new JButton ( toParent ) ) ;
    }

    private void init ( String title )
    {
        setSize ( 300, 300 ) ;
        setText ( title ) ;
        setTitle ( title ) ;
        setLayout ( new GridLayout ( 5, 1 ) ) ;
        setLocationByPlatform ( true ) ;
        setDefaultCloseOperation ( DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE ) ;

        add ( textField ) ;
    }

    public static void setValueFrom ( IHaveText dest, IHaveText source )
    {
        if ( null != dest && null != source )
        {
            dest.setText ( source.getText () ) ;
        }
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        new CustomFrame ().setVisible ( true ) ;
    }

    @ Override
    public void setText ( String text )
    {
        textField.setText ( text ) ;
    }

    @ Override
    public String getText ()
    {
        return textField.getText () ;
    }

}
```

p.s. для чего нужен интерфейс и какие задачи он выполняет, - вам придется разобратся самому :)

Comment: разберемся)