# Примеры java mvc pattern

Tags: mvc, java

Меня интересуют простые и понятные примеры с использованием Swing. Некоторые примеры нашел, пробовал самому писать небольшое приложение по принципу MVC. Но потом еще наткнулся на интерфейсы Observer и Observable. Обязательно ли использовать эти интерфейсы и есть ли небольшие примеры использования этих интерфейсов в паттерне MVC. И еще просьба посоветовать хорошую литературу по теме MVC в java.

Comment: смотря какую программу делаешь, но что то придумать можно...

Comment: MVC скорее концепция, нежели паттерн. Остальное сказал уже @jmu

Answer (score 1):

простой пример: [Передать текст из одного TextField в другой.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/174235)

p.s. паттерн MVC надо понять и уметь логически выделять все части. но это не означает что в вашем приложении обязательно каждая часть должна быть отделена от другой (потому что очень часто это сделать вообще невозможно).